# Как прекратить выполнение программы?

Tags: c, c#

Есть программа, написанная на C#, Windows.Form. 
Какой встроенной функцией мне прекратить выполнение программы?
Важно: необходимо не завершить процесс, а именно прекратить, чтобы можно было дальше работать с программой.

Пробовал функции `exit()` и `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` - после выполнения функций происходило закрытие формы.

Comment: >Важно: необходимо не завершить процесс, а именно прекратить. Что бы можно было дальше работать с программой

Эмм..это как?

Comment: Смотри, при вызове команды exit() идет закрытие программы(Windows Forms). А мне надо не закрывать, а просто закончить выполнение всех функций.

Comment: Извините конечно, но вы сами-то понимаете, чего хотите? Нет такого понятия как "закончить выполнение всех функций". Программа (и соответствующий ей процесс) либо запущена и работает, либо не запущена, и, соответсвенно, не работает. Выполняет ли она при этом какие-то действия или нет - это уже зависит от логики программы, нет такой волшебной функции, которая заставила бы программу магическим образом корректно завершить свою внутреннюю логику и при этом остаться в памяти.

Comment: Вы, конечно, можете сделать Thread.Sleep или Suspend, но эти методы лишь приостанавливают текущий поток, а не "заканчивают выполнение всех функций". При этом ваша программа просто зависнет

Comment: Я понял вас, спасибо за советы. Буду реализовывать return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, Ваша проблема выглядит так: программа зависла на какой-то операции, и нет возможности эту операцию прервать, чтобы продолжить работу с программой.

Для решения этой задачи операцию следует выполнять в фоновом потоке, ссылка на который доступна в Вашей программе. При необходимости прерывания этой операции нужно выполнить метод `Abort` у этого потока.